# Load resource dictionary at design time when using SDK format in project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I am currently converting my projects to the new SDK format of visual studio. Unfortunately I cannot get the designer to work. In the past I added an app.xaml with all design time relevant ressources into each of my projects. This leads to some warnings but visual studio gave me what I needed: Syntax Completion in the XAML designer

After I switched to the SDK format I got the error: `\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(225,9): error MC1002: Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element.` 
Therefore I deleted the app.xaml file but now I do not have Syntax Completion and the designer does not show my controls anymore.

What I have tried is to add a resource file and set

```
<Page Include="Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
</Page>
```

in the csproj file. But this trick does not work anymore because pages could not be defined in csproj file anymore..

How does Microsoft think this should work? Is there any way to add design time resources to my project without editing each of my 1000 xaml files?

I really want to avoid adding this to each of my xaml files:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Resources/ResourceBundle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: There is a GitHub [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3439) with the same problem

Comment: The designer itself is not the problem. The problem is are the design time ressources..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Page Update="Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml" Condition="'$(DesignTime)'=='true' OR ('$(SolutionPath)'!='' AND Exists('$(SolutionPath)') AND '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'!='true' AND '$(BuildingInsideExpressionBlend)'!='true')">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Adding this to the project file and my usercontrols are loading in design time again.. Unfortunatelly intellisense does still not work..